# how to not allow user to give special characters, numbers , spaces only in first place of word in html using regex

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, regex

How to not allow user to give special characters, numbers , spaces only in first place of word in html using regex.

```html
<label><span>Current Carrier</span></label>
<input name='Current Carrier'  type='text' class='form-control' pattern='[a-zA-Z]+$' for Physical Address'/>
```

Comment: What's the problem you are facing?

Comment: You are using the end of line anchor `$`, so you would be matching the last word `Carrier` in the example.  If you want to match the first word and make sure it starts at the beginning, use `^[a-zA-Z]+`, which is "start of line, one or more alpha"

Comment: You  should not use REGEX with HTML.  REGEX is for regular expressions and HTML is not regular.  There are too many special cases with HTML.  It is better to use a HTML parser.

Comment: If you do not want to match any string starting with a letter, please add more clarifications to the question and let know via a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
pattern="[A-Za-z].*"
```

*Details*:

- The pattern will be compiled into a `^(?:[A-Za-z].*)$` regex pattern that matches an ASCII letter at the start of string and then can contain any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, till the end of input string
- The `.*` is required because the `pattern` regex must match the whole input

See the live demo below:

```css
input:valid {
  color: black;
}

input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form name="form1">
  <input pattern="[A-Za-z].*" title="Please enter the data in correct format." />
  <input type="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try the carrot symbol in regex ->
Something like **/^[A-Za-z]/** -> this will match the first character and tells that it must be a letter, it cannot be a space, a number or a special character.

You can write the remaining regex after that.

Comment: 1) No need to use any anchors explicitly, the HTML engine will add both autmatically. 2) No need to use a regex literal notation, the HTML pattern regex should be a string, 3) A `^[A-Za-z]` pattern will only match inputs of a single letter. See my answer to understand why.